# Как добавить текст в конец textarea по клику?

Tags: jquery, html

Как с помошью JQuery написать такое, чтобы когда пользователь кликал по оределённой картинке в textarea в конец добавлялся текст?

```
<textarea name="textarea" cols="60" rows="9" class="textfield" id="textcoment">Вот сюда чтобы добавлялся!</textarea>
```

Текст вставляется разный! Картинок 11.

Comment: Картинок 1 или больше с обработчиком? Текст вставляется всегда одинаковый или в зависимости от нажатой картинки (если их больше 1)? Как на картинках отличается текст?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $('img').click(function(){
        var text = "text";
        $('#textcoment').append(text);
  });​
```

Answer (score 4):

Я так понимаю, мы об этом говорим?

```
    $('img').click(function(){
     var text = $(this).attr('alt');
     $('textarea').html(text);
   });​
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/XVgA3/)

Так?

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var text, text2, summa;
    text = $(this).attr('alt');
    text2 = $('textarea').html();
    summa = text2+' '+text;  
    $('textarea').html(summa);
});
```

[Пример2](http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/XVgA3/2/)

​

Или так

```
$('img').click(function(){  
text = $(this).attr('alt');
$('#textcoment').append(' '+text);    
});​
```

Comment: Почти так но не совсем я шочу чтобы если там уже будет текст добавлялось к нему

Comment: $('img').click(function(){
      var text = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('textarea').html( $('textarea').html() + text);
    });

Answer (score 2):

```
$('img').click(function(){
  document.getElementById('textcoment').value += $(this).attr('alt');
});​
```

Добавляет в textcoment текст из alt картинки

Comment: Красава Респект!

Comment: почему такая мешанина pure js и  jQuery?

Comment: Простите, а что должно мне помешать использовать javascript с javascript`ом? В данном случае .value += "текст" гораздо более удобная форма чем .val(.val() + "текст"). Использую jquery  там где это удобно (в данном случае выборки элементов и навешивание ивента на них) и pure js там где это удобнее. $(this).attr('alt') оставил в таком виде, так как сам текст может браться из разных источников. Может быть $(this).attr('alt'), а может оказаться и $(this).data('descritpion').

Comment: с эстетической точки зреня выглядит "не очень"

согласен += намного удобнее, но ведь `$('#textcoment')[0]` никто не отменял

Comment: $('#textcoment')[0] сделает тоже самое, только потратит на это больше времени. Я считаю конструкцию вида document.getElementById('textcoment').value += this.alt; лучше чем 
$('#textcoment')[0].value += $(this).attr('alt'); и потому так советую. Повторюсь конструкцию ($(this).attr('alt')) оставил исключительно для примера, так как в условии не было указано какой именно текст и откуда мы вставляем.